# How to design a chained Model.find() function?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, orm

I'm trying to write a ORM in Node.js. I want to declare a class named Model which will be used to declare a data object, like:

```
Users = new Model(someModelRules);
newUser = new Users(userInfomation);
```

the data model `User` have a function named `find()`. Now, I want to make `find()` chained, like:

```
Users.find(" name = 'John' ")
.orderedBy("age").desc()
.limit(0,10)
```

or maybe just a simply `find`:

```
Users.find(" name = 'John' ")
```

to code this `find` function, I believe I must build the SQL first,and do the SQL query at the end of this `find` chain.

I don't know how to do this, all I can think of is to add a function like: `doQuery()`, so I will know it's time to do the SQL query when the `doQuery()` function was called, like:

```
Users.find(" name = 'John' ")
.orderedBy("age").desc()
.limit(0,10)
.doQuery();
```

I know this is a simply solution, but I don't want the extra `doQuery()` function. :(

So, how should I design this? It would so nice of you if you can show me some example code with comments.

Thx! (sorry for my poor English)

ps. I know the [ORM2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2) has a find function I just want, but I wanna know how to code it and I can barely understand the code in ORM2 as there are no comments. (I'm not gonna use orm2.)

================================= SOLUTION ==============================

Inspired by @bfavaretto :

```
function User() {
    this.find = function(id, condition) {
        return new findChain(id, condition);
    }
}


function findChain(id, condition) {
    this._id = id
    this._condition = condition
    this.queryTimerSet = false;

    this.scheduleQuery = function () {
        var self = this;
        if(!self.queryTimerSet) {
            console.log('[TEST CASE: ' + self._id + '] Insert query into eventLoop');
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log('[TEST CASE: ' + self._id + '] Start query: '+self._condition);
            }, 0);
            self.queryTimerSet = true;
        } else {
            console.log('[TEST CASE: ' + self._id + '] No need to insert another query');
        }
    }

    this.orderedBy = function(column) {
        console.log('[TEST CASE: ' + this._id + '] orderedBy was called');
        this._condition = this._condition + ' ORDER BY ' + column
        this.scheduleQuery();
        return this;
    }

    this.desc = function() {
        // simply add DESC to the end of sql
        this._condition = this._condition + ' DESC'
    }

    this.scheduleQuery();

}


var user = new User();
user.find(1,'SELECT * FROM test').orderedBy('NAME1').desc();
user.find(2,'SELECT * FROM test').orderedBy('NAME2');
user.find(3,'SELECT * FROM test');
```

runnning this code, you will get the result:

```
[TEST CASE: 1] Insert query into eventLoop
[TEST CASE: 1] orderedBy was called
[TEST CASE: 1] No need to insert another query
[TEST CASE: 2] Insert query into eventLoop
[TEST CASE: 2] orderedBy was called
[TEST CASE: 2] No need to insert another query
[TEST CASE: 3] Insert query into eventLoop
[TEST CASE: 1] Start query: SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY NAME1 DESC
[TEST CASE: 2] Start query: SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY NAME2
[TEST CASE: 3] Start query: SELECT * FROM test
```

I believe there must be a better way to achieve this, but this is the best I can get for now.
Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve that if you schedule the `doQuery` logic to run asynchronously (but as soon as possible). I am thinking on something like this:

```
function User() {

    // Flag to control whether a timer was already setup
    var queryTimerSet = false;

    // This will schedule the query execution to the next tick of the
    // event loop, if it wasn't already scheduled.
    // This function is available to your model methods via closure.
    function scheduleQuery() {
        if(!queryTimerSet) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                // execute sql
                // from the query callback, set queryTimerSet back to false
            }, 0);
            queryTimerSet = true;
        }
    }

    this.find = function() {
        // ... logic that builds the sql

        scheduleQuery();
        return this;
    }

    this.orderedBy = function() {
        // ... logic that appends to the sql

        scheduleQuery();
        return this;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

---

One totally different approach is to have a single method for building the SQL, and passing the ORDER BY and LIMIT parameters in an options object. Then your call would look like this:

```
user.find({
    what : " name = 'John' ",
    orderedBy : "age DESC",
    limit : "0,10"
});
```

This is more suited for SQL queries than what you're trying to do. What you have looks like noSQL stuff like MongoDB, where fetching the records and sorting are separate operations (I think).

Comment: Okay...but it seems a sql query will be made each time a function was called(or almost). Correct me if I was wrong. Thank you, this is interesting, I'll try to think it this way.

Comment: The `queryTimerSet` flag is meant to avoid that. You'll only schedule a new query if the previous function didn't do that already.

Comment: I see... so the `scheduleQuery()` will run asynchronously, so the code won't wait for it and just `return this` ? but I think the `scheduleQuery()` is still running, and every function in the chain will call `scheduleQuery()` to run, so if I write a code like: `User.find("name='John'").orderedBy('age')` , there will be 2 `scheduleQuery()` running in the event loop. Am I right? (Sorry I'm a Node.js newbie)

Comment: @JeremyHou Actually, `scheduleQuery` is synchronous. Only the part that actually executes the query (inside `setTimeout`) is asynchronous. See this example running: http://jsfiddle.net/Cp8BW/. There is one major disadvantage in this approach: you cannot have two different `find()` calls in sequence, unless you somehow implement a way to force the execution of a pending query to start a new one.

Comment: I GOT IT! I think I can declare another class(let's call it `myQuery` ) which will have the `orderedBy()` , `limit()` , `scheduleQuery()`  functions, and each time a `find()` function was called, a new myQuery object was created and the `find()` function could call `newMyQuery.scheduleQuery(); return newMyQuery;`. Thus I can make multiple `find()`.  Thank you for pointing out a way to achieve this!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34110/discussion-between-jeremy-hou-and-bfavaretto)

Answer (score 0):

You will always have to have a execute/doQuery function at the end of the chain.
This is because all the other functions before the doQuery help build the query that needs to be executed at the end.

Comment: That will make a huge impact on the performance as it may make queries many times. I'd rather go the `doQuery()` way...... I believe there must be a way to do this. Thanks.